# Value of the function series

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find the real values so that the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2 x + 1}{3 - 4 x}\right)^{n}$$

Converges and I want to find the value of it

I think it is a geometric series such that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+2x}{3-4x}\right)^{n}={\color{red}{\frac{1}{- \frac{1+2x}{3-4x} + 1}}}$$

This is subject to $\left|{\frac{2 x + 1}{4 x - 3}}\right| < 1$ this is $x<\frac{1}{3}$ or $x>2$

I think that might be it, now if I want to wonder about the uniform convergence of the series.

It seems that it does not converge uniformly, but I have not been able to establish a real argument, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know the sum of an infinite geometric series?